# Executing and handling Void @Async operations from Spring Boot resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-async

Java 8 and Spring Boot 2.x here. I have a RESTful resource that will kick off a long-running operation, potentially taking 15 - 20 minutes to complete in some cases. I *think* I want to leverage the `@Async` annotation here in the service-layer, but I'm open to any good, elegant Spring Boot-savvy solution!

My best attempt thus far:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/v1/fizzbuzzes")
public class FizzbuzzResource {

    @Autowired
    private FizzbuzzService fizzbuzzService;

    @Autowired
    private FizzbuzzRepository fizzbuzzRepository;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fizzbuzz.ids")
    private List<String> fizzbuzzList;

    @PostMapping("/{fizzbuzzId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> runFizzbuzzOperations(@PathVariable String fizzbuzzId)
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        ResponseEntity responseEntity;

        // verify the fizzbuzzId is valid -- if it is, we process it
        Optional<Fizzbuzz> fbOpt = fizzbuzzRepository.lookupMorph(fizzbuzzId);
        if (fbOpt.isPresent()) {

            fizzbuzzList.add(fizzbuzzId);

            CompletableFuture<Void> future = fizzbuzzService.runAsync(fbOpt.get());
            future.get();
            // TODO: need help here

            // TODO: decrement the list once the async has completed -- ONLY do once async has finished
            fizzbuzzList.remove(fizzbuzzId);

            // return success immediately (dont wait for the async processing)
            responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok().build();

        } else {
            responseEntity = ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        return responseEntity;

    }

}

@Service
public class FizzbuzzService {

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<Void> runAsync(Fizzbuzz fizzbuzz) {

        // do something that can take 15 - 20 mins to complete
        // it actually is writing a massive amount of data to the file system
        // so there's nothing to really "return" so we just return null (?)

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);

    }

}
```

I *think* I'm close, but I'm struggling with:

- How to *properly* invoke `fizzbuzzService.runAsync(...)` in such a way that it actually runs asynchronously, and so that the `ResponseEntity.ok().build()` underneath it runs immediately, instead of waiting the ~15 minutes like it would have to otherwise; and
- How to run `fizzbuzzList.remove(...)` as soon as the async service method completes (again, some 15 - 20 mins later), but no sooner!; and
- Perhaps configure *some* type of timeout on the async operation, failing with an exception after, say, 30 minutes

**Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove call to [CompletableFuture.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--). It waits for future to    complete.
2. Pass consumer to [thenAccept](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAccept-java.util.function.Consumer-). You can find examples [here](https://dzone.com/articles/20-examples-of-using-javas-completablefuture).
3. For time outs, in Java 9, check [orTimeOut](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#orTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). Check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/completablefuture-timeouts-in-java) for example. If you check the article in previous link, in Java 8, there is no clean way of handling timeouts. You can set default timeout for entire application by providing custom async executor. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016943/spring-boot-how-to-set-async-timeout-when-deploying-to-an-external-server) stackoverflow question for solution.

Comment: Thanks @Adi (+1) - for #2 above, I assume that in _my case_ I would want to call `.join()` to make the consumer run asynchronously?

Comment: No, join will make it synchronous. It is similar to 'get' with a difference. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490316/completablefuture-join-vs-get.  You make call to 'fizzbuzzList.remove' in supplier passed to 'thenAccept'